# How to relate different parameters linked by a generic property

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I am in the following context:

```
type NumericLiteral = {
  value: number;
  type: "NumericLiteral";
};
type StringLiteral = {
  value: string;
  type: "StringLiteral";
};
type Identifier = {
  name: string;
  type: "Identifier";
};
type CallExpression = {
  name: string;
  arguments: DropbearNode[];
  type: "CallExpression";
};

type DropbearNode =
  | NumericLiteral
  | StringLiteral
  | Identifier
  | CallExpression;

type Visitor = {
  [K in DropbearNode["type"]]: (node: Readonly<Extract<DropbearNode, { type: K }>>) => void
};
```

I'd like to type a function `visitNode` that given a `DropbearNode` node `n` and a `Visitor` `v` is at least able to call `v[n.type]` on `n`: `v[n.type](n)`.

My first attempt was:

```
function visitNode<N extends DropbearNode>(node: Readonly<N>, v: Visitor) {
    v[node.type](node)
}
```

but it seems that TS considers `v[node.type]` and `node` completely unrelated, and I'm not sure I understand exactly what goes wrong. I mean, `node.type` becames `N["type"]` that is considered asssignable to the full union `"NumericLiteral" | "StringLiteral" | "Identifier" | "CallExpression"`, so at the end I think it expects as an argument an intersection of all the nodes' types, which is `never` of course because they form a discriminated union. What is going on here?

My second attempt was:

```
function visitNode<K extends DropbearNode['type']>(node: Readonly<Extract<DropbearNode, { type: K }>>, v: Visitor) {
   v[node.type](node)
}
```

in which I tried to impose a link between the two things. It seemed like a good idea, but I encountered a [design limitation](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48718) so I am forced to cast the `node.type` as `K` because TS is not able to reduce `typeof node.type` to it.

So, how could I properly type this function? And what are the reasons that make the first attempt wrong?

[TypeScript playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0&ts=4.7.0-dev.20220415#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwgJwJYGMAyrgoIYA2UAvFAN4BQUUAboXBAFxQB2iARigNxVSiTMARPCRosOfAUE8Avj37QAysDQsA5tlzJCJcrzoEGzAM4rU6ntQVDlqjRO1TZ88NACSAEwgtgqAGaoKLqU1Cx4SCZmFrzWUIKe3r4BKNIUchQKUADChAQAogAeYMgQxsaoAPYswbxhEVCmdpZQeMhqiInGzAAiyBVgnK0wFV4A2gC6zbGCOQT5RSVllSyp6RmuUL39g8jDXiS8AD6wHWKakkdQtub2WoSXCT7%20gciXs-PFpeVVPOuQUAA1VDlYAVZA1aijADSUHMmz6AwgQxGEFGggUgnG42YAAoWCjmAAlJEeKoEEAAHkKKjw6GAFK2iORXgANOQ%20K5mDCZAA%20HkAShIPNoFVQHjSvz8cBYdOWtGBOD2EAAjBSYFAIAVcCwPMZ4dskbsUTy8QSoMS8KSWOS1Ty2TRmECQWDBSFqLRRvivAA6BTjU1eflpCgUKUy3xVeUgpUAJgpMM12t1%20qZRrGAHIFOnxiavUxzSSyZTqdo6QyETslWyyByBFBuXz7Y6FaDkK7eB6877XP680H3R2aJ6Ud3-ng9VDeyigzIgA).

Comment: Does [this approach](https://tsplay.dev/N7O3qN) work for you?  This sort of correlated union type thing was essentially impossible to do this way before TS4.6, given [ms/TS#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  It was made possible in TS4.6 due to [indexed access inference improvements](//devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#indexed-access-inference-improvements), but you have to write your types a very particular way for the compiler to see the correlation. If this addresses your question I can write up an answer; otherwise, what am I missing?

Comment: @jcalz I think your approach is fine, I didn't know about this trick and I am going to study carefully those references. Anyway i think you can answer to the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside the implementation of `visitNode()`, both `v[node.type]` and `node` are of [union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#union-types) or generic types [constrained](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html#generic-constraints) to such a union.

Let's abbreviate `NumericLiteral`, etc. to `NL`, `SL`, etc., and `(t: T)=>void` as `Fn<T>`.  Then  `v[node.type]` is of a type assignable to `Fn<NL> | Fn<SL> | Fn<I> | Fn<CE>` and `node` is of a type assignable to `NL | SL | I | CE`.  **If that's all the compiler knows about the types** of `v[node.type]` and `node`, then it will not let you call `v[node.type](node)` without complaint.  As you know, a union of function types can only safely accept the [intersection](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#intersection-types) of its parameter types (at least as of TypeScript 3.3's introduction of [improved support for calling union types](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-3.html#improved-behavior-for-calling-union-types)), and  `NL | SL | I | CE` is not assignable to `NL & SL & I & CE`, so there's an error.

Such an error would be perfectly reasonable if you wrote `v[node1.type](node2)` where `node1` and `node2` were both of a generic type constrained to `NL | SL | I | CE`.  Maybe `node1` is of type `NL` but `node2` is of type `SL`.  In that case, `v[node1.type]` and `node2` would be of *independent* union types.

But that's not what's going on, is it?  `v[node.type]` and `node` are obviously *correlated* to each other.  If `node` is of type `NL` then `v[node.type]` is of type `Fn<NL>`.  It is always safe to call `v[node.type](node)`, but the compiler just can't see it!

This is the issue that prompted be to file the feature request at [microsoft/TypeScript#30581](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/30581).  Up to and including TypeScript 4.5, the only ways to deal with this situation were either to use a [type assertion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/everyday-types.html#type-assertions) to just suppress the warning, or to write redundant code to make one line per possible type for `node`.  Neither was great.

---

Luckily, TypeScript 4.6 introduced [improvements to generic indexed access inference](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/typescript/announcing-typescript-4-6/#indexed-access-inference-improvements) as implemented in [microsoft/TypeScript#47109](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/47109) to address this.

The trick is to write a mapping type whose keys are `DropbearNode['type']` and whose properties are the associated `node` types:

```
type TypeMap = { [K in DropbearNode["type"]]: Extract<DropbearNode, { type: K }> }
/* type TypeMap = {
    NumericLiteral: NumericLiteral;
    StringLiteral: StringLiteral;
    Identifier: Identifier;
    CallExpression: CallExpression;
} */
```

Then if we can represent the type of `node` in terms of an [indexed access](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/indexed-access-types.html) into this map, and if we can represent the type of `v` in terms of a similar [mapped type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/mapped-types.html) whose properties are also in terms of the same indexed access, the compiler will primed to see the correlation:

```
type Visitor = {
  [K in keyof TypeMap]: (node: Readonly<TypeMap[K]>) => void
};

function visitNode<K extends keyof TypeMap>(node: Readonly<TypeMap[K]>, v: Visitor) {
  v[node.type](node) // okay
}
```

(Note that this is not completely type safe; generic indices in contravariant positions have always been unsound in TS, you can write to `T[K]` even when `K` is a union.  So be careful.  Keep an eye on [ms/TS#48730](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48730) for updates here.)

Hooray!

---

Beware, though... this is finicky/fragile.  If you were to instead define `Visitor` explicitly as a set of properties like:

```
type Visitor = {
    NumericLiteral: (node: Readonly<NumericLiteral>) => void;
    StringLiteral: (node: Readonly<StringLiteral>) => void;
    Identifier: (node: Readonly<Identifier>) => void;
    CallExpression: (node: Readonly<CallExpression>) => void;
}
```

the same error from before would come back.  Even though this `Visitor` is structurally identical to the mapped type, the compiler is no longer ready to pay attention to the correlation. The mapped type with `TypeMap[K]` in it is crucial for this to work.  So be careful!

---

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?target=9&jsx=0&noErrorTruncation=true&ts=4.6.2#code/C4TwDgpgBAcgrgWwgJwJYGMAyrgoIYA2UAvFAN4BQUUAboXBAFxQB2iARigNxVSiTMARPCRosOfAUE8Avj37QAysDQsA5tlzJCJcrzoEGzAM4rU6ntQVDlqjRO1TZ88NACSAEwgtgqAGaoKLqU1Cx4SCZmFrzWUIKe3r4BKNIUchQKUADChAQAogAeYMgQxsaoAPYswbxhEVCmdpZQeMhqiInGzAAiyBVgnK0wFV4A2gC6zbGCOQT5RSVllSyp6RmuUL39g8jDXiS8AD6wHWKakkdQtub2WoSXCT7+gciXs-PFpeVVPOuQUAAVVwAWTwYGCUFGAGkoOZNn0BhAhiMIKNBApBONxsxCio8OhgAAeLaI5FeAA05D4rmYMJkAD4oDIKAB6ABU1P+QMgoPBpBC1BOogw50czBEKBFDkIzWo13UosIzHlt0ksqgjySL2Ymue3F41HehU+SyqzCNCy+y1kUDZLIof2gADVUOVgBVkDVqNDYdUANYQEAVPyAkFg7FQAAULBRzAASkiPFUCCBCdyILzoeN6QBKEiMmgVVAeNI8dmc52unAer2CiVnaUEZjR2NQBN4JMsFOE+tSu4EXP52hFjzqlWKptRmNeeOJ5Op8eNwfEAsj9W65LIZvTphtudd1Mbl7L1fF9UWk3fFjb1vtzvdi+LK8n4dntK2+0UPxwFgE5a0KtgD2CBCRhCAClwFgPGMKAAyDEN015ekWxnPcO3nNMwzALN6UpGhmBdN0PTzAUaFGHcADoFHGFCIDzFkWSgCo-TwEA0gdIA)

Comment: I've tested the `node2` approach with your solution and it seems to be unsound if there are multiple nodes as input. I am unable to share the link to the playground, but something similar happens [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48718#issuecomment-1100629818) as well, maybe i found a regression in that case.

Comment: I believe that for the single node case your solution is still the best. But for fairness and for future references, could you add two words for unsound cases like `visitNode<K extends keyof TypeMap>(node1: Readonly<TypeMap[K]>, node2: Readonly<TypeMap[K]>, v: Visitor)` where I am allowed to call `v[node1.type]` on `node2`, or viceversa? Thanks!

Comment: That's bizarre and really takes the wind out of my sails for this being "type safe".  I will put something in there when I get a chance but it might not be for a while as I am mostly indisposed today.

Comment: Oh I see there's a type assertion in there.  I have a feeling that the `K` from the two different `node`s is "marked" in some way by the compiler, and that `as K` undoes it.  I don't really know what the deal is without some word from the TS folks.

Comment: In my second attempt there is the `as K` type assertion, but it's not needed in your solution to create unsoundness. You can try yourself, I am unable to share the TS playground link here because it's too long and url shorteners are banned from SO

Comment: I've opened an issue https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/48730 to discuss the thing